# How would I use a button in Java to open an existing frame in the same package?

Tags: java, button, jframe

I have a bunch of jFrames in the same package. How would I go about opening all of them using buttons from one "Master Frame".

i.e, Master Frame named "Bob" has a bunch of buttons then will allow me to open jFrames that have already been created.

Answer (score 1):

In your event handler, do `newFrame.setVisible(true);`

Answer (score 0):

You could use this technique. I'm using it to set visible, but you could also use it for creation.

```
Map<String,Frame> myFrames = new HashMap<String,Frame>();
buttonForFrameA.setActionCommand("FRAME_A");
buttonForFrameB.setActionCommand("FRAME_B");

myFrames.put("FRAME_A",aFrame);
myFrames.put("FRAME_B",bFrame);



public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getActionCommand().startsWith("FRAME_") {
        for(Frame frame : myFrames.values()) 
            frame.setVisible(false);
        Frame selectedFrame = myFrames.get(e.getActionCommand());
        if(selectedFrame != null) selectedFrame.setVisible(true);

}
```